# "Расширение" Vue компонента

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap

Итак, есть компонент [BModal](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal) в комплекте Bootstrap Vue. Конкретно интересует переделка `modal-header` слота - хочу накинуть на него пару кнопок и в целом немного расширить функционал компонента.

Проблема в том, что надо прокинуть все свойства, события и прочие объекта в сам компонент `b-modal`. Снова прописывать все эти объекты у себя в компоненте только ради того, чтобы слегка добавить функционала как-то слишком геморно. На просторах интернета наткнулся на пример, по которому пытался решить свою проблему:

```
<template>
    <b-modal v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
        <template v-for="(index, name) in $scopedSlots" v-slot:[name]="data">
            <slot :name="name" v-bind="data"></slot>
        </template>
    </b-modal>
</template>
```

Однако, по какой-то причине это не помогает - все объекты вроде передаются, но реакции никакой нет. По крайней мере, у `b-modal` есть `v-model`, которая контролировала видимость модалки, но в этом случае оно просто не работает. Что я делаю не так и как можно решить мою проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было в свойствах компонента объявить:

```
model: {
    prop: 'visible',
    event: 'change'
}
```

И теперь все работает. По умолчанию `v-model` использует `prop` `value` и `event` `input`, поэтому свойство видимости не пробрасывалось.